# Validate textboxes and dropdowns inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've tried looking for this across StackOverflow and other sites, but can't find anything that matches my issue.  Basically, I have a gridview with a dropdown menu and a textbox contained in the rows.  The users need to select an option from the dropdown and depending on the option they select, they may also need to add some data to the textbox in the same row.  As part of this I want to run validation to alerts users as to which fields they've not completed - but I want to try and do this in asp.net C# if possible (not using JavaScript, or JQuery, or anything else if I can avoid it).

I've been able to get so far: if the dropdown isn't selected, or text isn't entered, the gridview will validate - but it puts an error message against every row, even if only one row is incorrect, whereas I only want the validation message to appear on those rows which aren't.

My code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCurrentServicesGrid" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdviewCurrentSystems" CssClass="table-data currentSystemTable" UseAccessibleHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="systemName" HeaderText="Service" ItemStyle-Width="10%"/>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="39%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="aspdropSystemStatus" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" />
                            <div style="display:none">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="RowId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                            </div>
                            <div style="display:none">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="SelectedVal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("systemStatus") %>' />
                            </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Further information" ItemStyle-Width="50%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSystemStatusInfo" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="300" CssClass="textarea1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("systemInformation") %>' />
                                <asp:CustomValidator
                                    CssClass="CustomValidator1"
                                    OnServerValidate="grdviewFurtherInfo_Validate" 
                                    Display="Dynamic"
                                    runat="server"
                                    ValidationGroup="valgrpLocal">
                                        <asp:ValidationMessageLocal 
                                            CssClass="aspvalmsgLocal" 
                                            ID="aspvalSystemStatus" 
                                            Title="Service statuses" 
                                            TextPassed="" 
                                            TextFailed="Check Status or Further Information fields" 
                                            runat="server" />
                                    </asp:CustomValidator>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDelSystem" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lnkbtnDelSystem_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete(this.id); return false;" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server">
                                <span class="btn btn-small btn-spinner btn-grid">X</span> 
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my code behind is:

```
protected void grdviewFurtherInfo_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{

    bool valid = true;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdviewCurrentSystems.Rows)
    {
        usercontrols_asp_formctl_dropdownlist aspDrop = (usercontrols_asp_formctl_dropdownlist)row.FindControl("aspdropSystemStatus");
        usercontrols_asp_formctl_textbox aspTxt = (usercontrols_asp_formctl_textbox)row.FindControl("txtSystemStatusInfo");


        if (aspDrop.SelectedValue == "")
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        else if (aspDrop.SelectedValue != "1" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(aspTxt.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        e.IsValid = valid;
    }


}
```

Can anyone please advise?

Thank you! :)

Comment: That link doesn't appear to work for me - is it definitely live?

Comment: Check now - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-only-certain-selected-GridView-Row-Controls-like-TextBox-using-ASPNet-Validators.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of for each loop.

```
    int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((DropDownList )sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
         usercontrols_asp_formctl_dropdownlist aspDrop = (usercontrols_asp_formctl_dropdownlist)grdviewCurrentSystems.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("aspdropSystemStatus");
            usercontrols_asp_formctl_textbox aspTxt = (usercontrols_asp_formctl_textbox)grdviewCurrentSystems.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("txtSystemStatusInfo");
 if (aspDrop.SelectedValue == "")
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        else if (aspDrop.SelectedValue != "1" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(aspTxt.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        e.IsValid = valid;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work and I get an error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'.  I'm still really new to the whole asp.net thing, so I'm not sure what it is I've done here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CustomValidator` for each row in the GridView.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Input incorrect" ValidationGroup='<%# "valGroup_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' ClientValidationFunction="myValidator" ControlToValidate="aspdropSystemStatus" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And for the client side script outside of the gridview:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myValidator(oSrc, args) {
        //get the rownumber that fires the validator
        var rowNumber = oSrc.id.split("_")[3];
        //get the id of the dropdown of the row
        var DropDownID = "mainContentPane_grdviewCurrentSystems_aspdropSystemStatus_" + rowNumber;
        //get the id of the textbox of the row
        var TextBoxID = "mainContentPane_grdviewCurrentSystems_txtSystemStatusInfo_" + rowNumber;
        //is the row correctly filled out
        if (document.getElementById(DropDownID).selectedIndex > 0 && document.getElementById(TextBoxID).value == "") {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

For this to work you have to do the following:

Add `ValidationGroup='<%# "valGroup_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'` to each element that needs validating in the row and the save button. The validation group name is made unique by adding the `Container.DataItemIndex` (row number) to the name. If it is not unique it will validate all rows as a single group and that is not what you want I think.

Check if `oSrc.id.split("_")[3];` get you the row number. In my case the ID's look like this `mainContentPane_grdviewCurrentSystems_CustomValidator1_1` so that is why we need the 3rd value after the splitting of the ID.

Check the id's of the DropDown and TextBox(es) you want to validate and set them as variables in the javascript. If the ID looks like this `mainContentPane_grdviewCurrentSystems_aspdropSystemStatus_0` just remove the row number and replace it with the `rowNumber` of the javascript.